# shell script - open ssh connect and send commands when needed

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, console

Is it possible to open ssh connect in bash script and send commands through it when it needed.

I want to put some logic between commands and use one connection.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Comment: But if you just want to "put some logic between commands and use one connection", put the commands in a server-side shell script instead.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing

Answer (score 1):

With a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user@server << EOF
echo $HOSTNAME 
hostname
echo Hello
EOF
```